# Issue with the train_test_split function of sklearn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
dataset,labels = shuffle(dataset,labels)
print("Shuffling of dataset is completed")
print(" ")

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda doc: doc, lowercase=False)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([dataset])


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,labels,test_size=0.1,stratify=labels)
print("Completing the splitting of data.")
print(" ")
```

This is a classification model which I am building using sklearn library.

I am getting an error by the function **train_test_split()** where the error states :

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 88702]

I have tried to resolve this error through different methods which were present like changing the shape of X and Y but still I am not able to get desired result.

Comment: Can you show me the shape of X and labels?  What is the dataset look like?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the length of your X vector does not equal the length of your labels vector.  If you print the shapes of the X vector I would expect it to be of length 1.

It seems like the line

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([dataset])
```

should be changed to

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset)
```

according to the documentation for sklearn.feature_extraction.text found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)